# problems using the ppa command on terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu

each time i run the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
on the linux terminal i get the following errors

```
> You are about to add the following PPA to your system:  Oracle Java
> (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK6 /
> JDK7 / JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA. 
> 
> More info: 
> - for Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html
> 
> Debian installation instructions:
> http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html
> Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 160, in <module>
>     sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py",
> line 96, in __init__
>     self.reload_sourceslist()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py",
> line 584, in reload_sourceslist
>     self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 87, in
> get_sources
>     raise NoDistroTemplateException("Error: could not find a " aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a
> distribution template
```

Please how do i fix these issues

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Please i need help on how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have to update you distro templae as it is stated [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966730)